# UISegmentControl customize not working in ios 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

The below code is working fine in ios 6 but not working in ios 7

```
for (id segment in [cell.m_CtrlSegment subviews]) {

            for (id label in [segment subviews]) {

                if ([label isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {

                    UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *) label;

                    //inserting line here, to make the frame behave nicely:
                    //
                    titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, (cell.m_CtrlSegment.frame.size.width/DownloadCount)-4,40);
                    titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                    titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                    titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
                    titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
                    titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
                    titleLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
                    titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

                }
            }
        }
```

The color of the labels remains blue , but when select one of the index the code works.

Comment: There is hierarchy changed in iOS7,so Put a break here and check the sub-views and super-view of the UISegmentControllView and according to views hierarchy customize the desired sub-views.

Answer (score 1):

You should really not use these kind of hacks, your app could be rejected for this reason

> 2.5
>
> We also found that your app interacts with the organization and layout
>   of a provided view's internal hierarchy, which is a private entity.
>   Interacting with private entities is not in compliance with the App
>   Store Review Guidelines.

The [appearance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISegmentedControl/backgroundImageForState%3abarMetrics%3a) proxy is the best when it comes to customization and availaible from iOS5.

Relying on this kind of hierarchy hacks will likely also to break in future iOSes as you are experimenting.